# jQuery UI tabs nested tabs events triggering and binding

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using nested [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/VvFyM/1/

I'm trying to bind to the **tabsselect** event separately for both the outside tabs and the nested tabs. Problem is, whenever the nested tab's tabsselect event is triggered, it seems that either:

1. The outside tab's tabsselect handler **catches it as well**, or
2. The outside tab's select event is **also triggered** (hence it is caught).

Which is it?

Then, is there a way to trigger and bind the 2 events separately?

So, instead of

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(ev, ui){
    console.log("Tab selected");
})
```

I want to do something like

```
$("#tabs").bind("/*tabsselect outside tabs only*/", function(ev, ui){
    console.log("Tab selected");
})
```

and

```
$("#tabs").bind("/*tabsselect inside tabs only*/", function(ev, ui){
    console.log("Tab selected");
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding the select function after initialization bind it while you initialize the tabs and that solves the problem. I updated your fiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/R5sSh/

Comment: thanks a lot that worked. As a follow up, how can I get it such that I can control it to generate a sub-tab select event when I click on a main tab? Basically, When I click on the main tab, I want it to defer to a sub tab's select event.

Comment: This is getting to be a different question but what you could possibly do is create a seperate function for the subtabs selection event and then call it from both the tab and subtab selection bindings. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5sSh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can remove the `ui-tabs-selected` and `ui-tabs-active` classes, then you can use `$('#tabscontainer').tabs( "select", hashOrIndex );`